# Releasing project in android studio

Tags: android, project, release

How long usually does it take to release a project in android studio? our project app has 49 Megabyte and when we tried to release it. it takes forever to get completed. it's been 4 hrs since i tried to released it and now its still running. My laptop has no issues because it has 8 Gigabyte ram and it is fast whenever i run it to test my application. any suggestion or any tips on how can i make this a little bit faster? I am being confused on how can i release my project in android studio.

Comment: under *release* you mean *build a release variant*? I think it just got stuck. CHeck if ANdroid Studio or Java process is using the CPU, and if it is not using - it likely got stuck.

Comment: "My laptop has no issues because it has 8 Gigabyte ram" that's quite an assumption, it also depends on the os you're running and which other processes you're running at the same time. Anyhow, I recommend you to monitor your processes so you can see how much ram Studio is actually using, and also set up a higher default ram for Studio itself. Also worth for you to monitor where your release process is hanging.

Comment: Any explanation why it has a chance to get stuck? and how am i able to check if the android studio is using CPU? im sorry im just a newbie in android i never had an experience releasing it. it's for my project to be released and i am worried because the deadline oh the released APK is on the other day.

Comment: `under release you mean build a release variant?`???

Comment: @Vlad i only need the released APK of my project i tried to release another projet which only has 1MB and it released successfully but my main project which has 49 MB which is  too long to get completed is still running until now and it been 5 hrs already. you think the reason of this is because of large mb that causing this delay?

Comment: Ok, let me explain. You can't release anything using ANdroid Studio. ANdroid Studio can only **build things**. I'm asking for 3rd and last time: what do you mean by saying that you are trying to release?

Comment: Im sorry im just a little bit nervous right now. The apk of my project.

Comment: SO you are trying to build a release version of APK?

Comment: @Vlad yes sir. i am trying to generate its own APK.

Comment: ok. Which OS are you building on?

Comment: My target version is 27 and the minimum is 22 sir

Comment: Try to set minifyEnabled to false in gradle file > buildTypes > release

Comment: i will definitely try this sir. thanks. and i ill update you :)

Comment: sir it is already false when i tried to generate earlier

Comment: no, which OS are you running you ANdroid Studio on? WIndows, Linux, MacOS...?

Comment: Im sorry. windows sir.

Comment: another question can i possibly see the progress count of the build progress itself? can i want to know the percent for it to get completed

Comment: open the task manager, and check which processes consume CPU there. If none of ANdroid Studio or Java processes does - then it likely got stack, and you probably need to restart the build process. Android Studio does not show the progress unfortunately

Comment: it somehow getting 2-5% in the CPU pointing out the android studio but sometimes it goes back to 0% is it okay?

Comment: it consumes alot of memory ill tell you. it has 990MB im talking about the android studio haha do you think its the reason why is it so slow to build? because of the file size? or another reason ?